# Why does "require" compile but "import" does not?

Tags: node.js, typescript, compiler-errors, node-modules

I am new to `TypeScript/JavaScript` and `Node.js` and writing a simple script to run in command line.

I installed [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) dependency and added `import archiver from 'archiver';` to my script.
When I compile the script with `tsp -p .` the `import` does not compile:

```
error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'archiver'. <my script path> implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/archiver` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'archiver';`

6 import archiver from 'archiver';
                       ~~~~~~~~~~
```

However `const archiver = require('archiver');` does compile. Now I wonder what's wrong with the import.

Comment: Did you do what the error message tells you to do?

Comment: Sure. However I installed `@types/archiver` _instead of_ `archiver` because I did not understand I need them both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed the npm packages without the types, meaning the pure JS package. You would need to run `npm install @types/archiver`, provided this package supports Typescript. The standard for JavaScript (ES6/2015) suggests to use `import` and not the `require`.

Comment: Thanks ! That's why they say `Try npm install @types/archiver`. I guess I should install it _in_  _addition_ to `archiver`.

Comment: Yes! Forgot to mention that.